# Continuum limit of $ \sum_{r=1}^\infty \sum_{z=1}^\infty a_r |r z \rangle \langle r z | = \sum_{l=1} b_l |l \rangle \langle l | $?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, solution-verification, mathematical-physics

### Background

Using [bra-ket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) notation consider the identity (for integer $r$) :

$$ \sum_{z=1}^\infty |r z \rangle \langle r z |  =   I \otimes \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}}_{\dim r} 
$$

with $I$ begin the identity matrix. Multiplying an arbitrary constant $a_r$ both sides:

$$ \sum_{z=1}^\infty a_r |r z \rangle \langle r z | = I \otimes   \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &0 & a_r
  \end{bmatrix}}_{\dim r} 
$$

Now, summing over $r$:

$$ \sum_{r = 1}^\infty \sum_{z=1}^\infty a_r |r z \rangle \langle r z | dz = I \otimes \sum_{r = 1}^\infty   \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &0 & a_r
  \end{bmatrix}}_{\dim r} 
$$

Let us explicitly handle the R.H.S:

$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
    a_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & a_1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &0 & a_1
  \end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & a_2 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &0 & a_2
  \end{bmatrix}
+ \dots
$$

Hence with  $b_r = \sum_{i|r} a_i $

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty  \sum_{z=1}^\infty a_r |r z \rangle \langle r z |  =   {\begin{bmatrix}
    b_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & b_2 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 &  b_3 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &0 & \ddots
  \end{bmatrix}}  = \sum_{l=1} b_l |l \rangle \langle l | 
$$

### Question

Is the above proof correct?  With  $b_r = \sum_{i|r} a_i$:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty  \sum_{z=1}^\infty a_r |r z \rangle \langle r z |  = \sum_{l=1} b_l |l \rangle \langle l | 
$$

Is there a continuum limit of this formula? Does  $ \sum_{z=1}^\infty |r z \rangle \langle r z |$ have a continuum analog?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by $$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}}_{\dim r} \otimes I.
$$
If we are to take this definition at face value, then it seems as though the "matrices" $|1z \rangle\langle 1z|$ and $|2z \rangle\langle 2z|$ have different sizes

Comment: Also, note that the phrase "continuum limit" is not commonly used outside of a physics setting. I suspect that you are referring to something like
$$
\lim_{M,N \to \infty}\sum_{r = 1}^M \sum_{z=1}^N a_r |r z \rangle \langle r z |,
$$
but this should be explicitly clarified.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom they are both infinite dimensional matrices and by continuum  limit I meant something like $\sum |x \rangle \langle x | \to \int |x  \rangle  \langle x| dx $

Comment: Back to point one: so with the expression
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & a_2 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &0 & a_2
  \end{bmatrix},
$$
are you saying that each entry is supposed to represent an infinite submatrix? That is, are you saying that the diagonal has a $0$ infinite matrix, followed by $a_2I$?

Comment: Apologies got the order of the tensor product wrong

Comment: That's an improvement, but your notation is still problematic. For instance, even the statement 
$$
I = I \otimes \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}
$$
would be incorrect in the conventional setting